# Json split python larger file memory issues

Tags: python, json, split, size, volume

Am new to python. I am trying to split the json into multiple files based on the objects in the json file. Each objects goes as each unique file. The script i got is below, which does the job perfect but having memory issues, when we run huge volume of files (1000 files) each 10 MB and has around 8k objects.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import os
import shutil
import time
import sys
import commands
import pwd
from collections import OrderedDict


b = commands.getstatusoutput('ps -ef | grep splitjson.py | wc -l')
c = int(b[1])

if c > 3:
 print c
else:
 print c
 
 path = '/home/subhome/json2/' # Get current working directory
 kpath = '/home/subhome/jskaf/' # Destination path
 jepath = '/home/subhome/jskaf/err/' # The error path to move the not well formated json file
 apath = '/home/subhome/jskaf/arch/' # The archive path of all the files.
 direc = os.listdir(path)
 print(path)
 # Iterate over files in directory
 for f in direc:
     name,ext = os.path.splitext(f)
     a=f.split('.json')[0]
     obpath=path + f
     print obpath
     kfpath=kpath + a
     jerrpath=jepath + a
     arcpath=apath + a
     with open(obpath) as fl:
      try:
       #data2=json.loads(fl.read())
       docs = json.load(fl,object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
       for ii, doc in enumerate(docs):
         with open(kfpath+'.{}.json'.format(ii), 'w') as out:
            outflname=kfpath+'.'+str(ii)
                  json.dump(doc, out, indent=2)
       shutil.copy(obpath,arcpath)
       os.remove(obpath)
      except ValueError as e:
       print("An exception occurred")
       errdata = str(e)
       print(e)
       shutil.copy(obpath,jerrpath)
       os.remove(obpath)
```

Comment: So the issue is that a single input json is large enough to cause a memory error, or you have some memory leak when you process many input jsons in a loop?

Comment: For one file works perfectly fine, only if its more than 2 files it hungs